# How to download some specific files with some keywords from different directories using wget?

Tags: download, directory, wget

I am trying to download data from TRMM satellite data archive using the following command
`wget -r --no-parent ftp://arthurhou.pps.eosdis.nasa.gov/pub/trmmdata/ByDate/V07/2008/01/01 --user=--user= --password="`
2008 is the year, 01 is for January and 01 is for 01 is for the date. Within this date folder, there are plenty of data files
(`e.g 1A01.20080101.57701.7.gz, 2A21.20080101.57711.7.HDF.gz, 2A23.20080101.57702.7.HDF.gz`).
I want to download only the files under "2A23" category from every folder (e.g year, month and date), but with my wget command all the files are getting downloaded. Is there a way to specify some key to download just those files?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is here, if someone is stuck at the same question later.

```
wget -r --no-parent -A 'pattern' 'URL' --user=--user= --password=
```

In my case the pattern was `2a23*.gz`.